# React: React Input Field not editable after i set data to state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know what might be wrong here, but i am following a tutorial and writing the same lines of code, but it seems that i am getting an error when i add this block of code.

```
setTeacherLoginData({
      ...teacherLoginData,
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    
});
```

i am thinking that my error is related to this.

> Since the value attribute is not updating, it's not possible to edit the given input field. You can solve this by adding an onChange event and the value attribute to the input field

this is the code i have written so far

```
const [ teacherLoginData, setTeacherLoginData ] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',

    });

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setTeacherLoginData({
      ...teacherLoginData,
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    
    });
    };

    const submitForm = () => {
        console.log(teacherLoginData);
    };


return (
    <input value="{teacherLoginData.email}" onChange="{handleChange}" type="text" className="form-control" />
    <input value="{teacherLoginData.password}" onChange="{handleChange}" type="password" className="form-control" />
    <button onClick="{submitForm}" className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
)
```

Comment: You're using `event.target.name`, but it doesn't look like your `input` elements have `name` attributes?

Comment: @JoeClay Please make this comment an answer so i can accept it, it solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issues that peetzweg's answer mentions, you are missing `name` attributes on your form inputs. This means that the `event.target.name` in your `handleChange` function will not be populated.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing literal strings into the props of your html `<input/>` and `<button/>`.

This makes sense in vanilla HTML to set attributes of the `<input/>` and `<button/>` tags, but this is not what you want in React, which uses `JSX` instead of `HTML` syntax.

HTML Example:

```html
<input value="{teacherLoginData.email}" onChange="{handleChange}" type="text" className="form-control" />
```

In React we write JSX which is something like JS + HTML.
Here we speak of `props` instead of `attributes` for a html element. You pass  props similar to html, however you can pass javascript objects as well using the `{}` braces.

JSX:

```html
<input value={teacherLoginData.email} onChange={handleChange} type="text" className="form-control" />
```

Noticed I remove the `""` from the `value` and `onChange` prop to actually pass the functions instead of a string containing "teacherLoginData.email".

If you use quotes you are passing a string instead of the actual javascript reference of a function. For some props it's intended to pass a string i.e. the `type` & `className` prop of this `<input/>`.

Here is a link to the docs of JSX to get you familiar with it:
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html